# How can i make a Timer in Python?

Tags: python, timer

I try to make a Timer in python but it doesn`t work.
every time there is an error message

```
from time import sleep
import os

def countdown(time = 5):
    while time != 0:
        print(time)
        sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')
        time -= 1
        if time == 0:
            print("Time is going up")

time = input('Input number of seconds to countdown: ')
countdown(time)
```

**Error Message:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: `input` return a string. May be you need `time = int(input(...))`

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that the integer and string type mixing

Here is the code that works fine:

```
from time import sleep
import os

def countdown(time = 5):
    while time != 0:
        print(time)
        sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')
        time -= 1
        if time == 0:
            print("Time is going up")

time = int(input('Input number of seconds to countdown: '))
countdown(time)
```

**I have just stored `time` in `int` type (Your were storing in string type)**